# How do add a class using jQuery upon script completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Problem:**

Adding a CSS class to an input field once a jQuery script has been completed. The script is a dice function that will randomly generate 1 to 6 upon clicking on it. The number will be stored in a variable called **result**. I want to check the number in **result** and add a class to the input field that has that number in the value attribute.

**JS code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.dice').on('click','li',function(){
                $('.cube').attr('class','cube '+$(this).attr('data-opt'))
            }).on('click','.select',function(){
                $('.dice').toggleClass($(this).attr('data-opt'))
            }).on('click','#spin',function(){
                var result = Math.round(Math.random()*5 + 1)
                , angle = {}
            $(this).data('n',$(this).data('n')?0:5);
            var n = $(this).data('n');
            $('.cube').attr('style','');
            angle = {x:360*n,y:360*n}

            switch (result){
              case 1:
                break;
              case 2:
                angle.y = 360*n + 90;
                break;
              case 3:
                angle.x = 360*n - 90;
                break;
              case 4:
                angle.x = 360*n + 90;
                break;
              case 5:
                angle.y = 360*n - 90;
                break;
              case 6:
                angle.x = 360*n + 180;
                break;
            }
            $('.cube').css({'-webkit-transform':'translateZ(-100px) rotateX(' + angle.x + 'deg) rotateY(' + angle.y + 'deg)','-webkit-transition':'3s'})

            $.ajax ({
                url: 'savedice.php',
                data: {"diceId": result},
                type: 'post',
                success: function(data) {
                    //Success
                }
            });

        })
  });
</script>
```

**HTML code:**

```
<input class="number" name="alternative[]" type="text" value="1">
<input class="number" name="alternative[]" type="text" value="2">
<input class="number" name="alternative[]" type="text" value="3">
<input class="number" name="alternative[]" type="text" value="4">
<input class="number" name="alternative[]" type="text" value="5">
<input class="number" name="alternative[]" type="text" value="6">
```

I have looked at and tried to use addClass() but I haven't been able to figure out how I check first the variable **result** against the different input field.

If the variable **result** has number 4 then I want to add a CSS class to input field that has value 4. **Not requesting a solution**, but appreciate rather guidance in this issue.

Comment: can you provide the fiddle of it?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if(result == 4){
     $('input[value="4"]').addClass('someclass');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this -

```
if(result == 4){
  $('.number').filter(function(){return this.value === result;}).addClass('someClass');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the value of the input fields in `result` , as you are saying in the question

try like this:

```
$('input.number[value="'+result+'"]').addClass("MyClass");
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XuE4p/) [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XuE4p/)